# Horizontal Fling starts only on offset 0

Tags: android, gestures, onfling

I am trying to implement fling. Problem is that I get it only when the X is on offset 0 (which means on the edge of the screen). When I try to have a fling in the middle of the screen nothing happens. This happens only on X. Y behaves OK. 
Here is the code:

```
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    try {

        if ((e1.getY() < CARD_POSITION) && (e2.getY() < CARD_POSITION)
                && (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) >SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE )
                ) {
            Log.v("Fling:",Double.toString(e1.getX())); 
            return true;
        } else {


            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've encoutered a similar issue in the past. It ended up being a error in the math of how I was comparing the x loction to the min distance threshold I was using. Based on what you're describing in combination with the code posted, it sounds as though the x direction fling is not working beacuse the different between x1 and x2, after applying absolute value, is not coming out to what you think.

From 0 offset, swiping the whole screen, you're able to register a fing because, with that much distance, the different between the 2 values is enough to trigger your threshold. But from the middle of the screen, say where x1 = 400 and x2 = whever the move event is registered, you're not triggering that threshold.

What worked for me was removing absolute value

```
public boolean onFling(MovtionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){

if(e2.getX() - e1.getX() > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX)){
    Log.d("Swipe", "Left to right")
    return true;
} else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX)){
    Log.d("Swipe", "Right to Left")
    return true;
}
```

My reasoning was based on the [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) docs which describe what e1 and e2 represent:

> e1  The first down motion event that started the scrolling.
>   e2  The
>   move motion event that triggered the current onFling.

The error turned out to be an assumption in where th e1 intial `ACTION_DOWN` occurred relative to the `ACTION_MOVE` from e2